# How to get a function for the voltage across a capacitor connected to an AC voltage source?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

I am looking for the way of obtaining a solution for $V_{c}$ ,as a function of $t$ depending of $\omega$, of the following differential equation related to an electrical circuit involving a low-pass filter : $ \frac{ d V_{c}(t)}{d{t}} + \frac{V_{c}(t)}{\tau} = \frac{V_{s}(t)}{\tau} $.

where, 
$V_{c}$ is the voltage across the capacitance, 
$V_{s}$ is the voltage given by the AC voltage source,
$\tau$ is the time constant,

considering that,

$\tau = R C$ ,

$V_{s} = V_{in} \sin{( \omega t )}$ ,

$I_{R} = I_{C} = \frac{V_{s}(t) - V_{c}(t)}{R} = C \frac{dV_{c}(t)}{dt}$.

I approached the problem by first solving the homogeneous part ( $ \frac{ d V_{c}(t)}{d{t}} + \frac{V_{c}(t)}{\tau} = 0$ ) and for which I get the following solution :
$V_{c}(t) = K e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}$ (where $K$ is a constant).

I now need find the particular solution (to get the general solution : $S_{general} = S_{homogeneous} + S_{particular}$ ). I think the particular solution might be of the type : $V_{c}(t) = A \cos{(\omega t + \phi)}$.

Edit : Once I replace the particular solution in the equation, I come to something depending on $\omega$ , $\phi$ and $\frac{A}{V_{in}}$ , but I don't see how to continue using the sum function sum formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just plug in your suggested solution, you get $$\frac d{dt}  A\cos(\omega t + \phi)+\frac 1{\tau}A\cos(\omega t + \phi)=\frac{V_{in}}\tau\sin(\omega t)\\ -A\omega \sin(\omega t + \phi)+\frac 1{\tau}A\cos(\omega t + \phi)=\frac{V_{in}}\tau\sin(\omega t)$$  Now you should be able to use the function sum formulas to solve for $\phi$ and $\frac A{V_{in}} $